# SVN Working copy merge without server

Tags: svn, merge

In Subversion, how can I merge between working copies, from trunk to branch, without communicating to the server (both are at their latest revision with no local changes).

Comment: You just want them to become the same? It doesn't really make sense merging two working copies. What's the point of reference for the difference?

Answer (score 2):

Merging in Subversion means that you want to merge the changes from revision `xyz` to revision `xyz + i` on the branch `branch_abc` to the current state of the trunk. That means, that you are only able to do that, if you know the difference between `xyz` and `xyz + i` and that is only known to the server.

So, no, there is no way to do the merge only locally (without connection to the server).

Answer (score 0):

It does not look like you can, from svn-book:

> `2. merge sourceWCPATH1@N sourceWCPATH2@M [WCPATH]`
>
> `3. merge [-c M[,N...] | -r N:M ...] SOURCE[@REV] [WCPATH]`
>
> `2. In the second form, the URLs corresponding to the source working copy paths`
>   `define the sources to be compared.  The revisions must be specified.`
>
> `3. In the third form, SOURCE can be either a URL or a working copy path`
>   `(in which case its corresponding URL is used).`

The docs say even though you're referencing a copy on disk, it's still going to try to go the repository.

I tried merging like you suggested (the second form, from above), and it worked when connected, but when I disconnected:

```
dev_6 zyoung$ svn merge --reintegrate ../dev@11
svn: OPTIONS of 'http://foo.unfuddle.com/svn/foo_personal/dev': Could not resolve hostname `foo.unfuddle.com': Host not found (http://foo.unfuddle.com)
```

I hope this helps,